# "WordPress X.X is available! Please update now" is not showing?

Tags: php, wordpress

In all WP version...whenever new version release then you will get a notification to upgrade your existing WP. But due to some reason I am not getting this option. Last time I upgraded WP setup manually. But this time I want one click upgrade option so that I can upgrade easily.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured in the wp-config.php file that the following line is in it?

define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true);

Here is an article that might help.
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/auto-update.htm

Comment: I have tried this before...but this is not working for my website ? anything else ?

Comment: Yes...anything else except this ?